# how resolve gradle error "This project does not use the Gradle build system"

Tags: android, github

I  cloned a project from Github when i try to build the project an error shown in android studio ."This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
More Information about migrating to Gradle
Don't show this message again".it's seem this projects it's not created witha android studio

Comment: Which branch are you using? Is it master branch?

Comment: I am just to try to clone this https://github.com/Brummi/VRDemo

Comment: The project you are importing is not android studio project. It is eclipse project so the issue is due to not getting main build.gradle file

Comment: what should i do to make migrate for this project

Comment: this problem is not for this project only for other project same prolem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clone by 
**VCS -> Checkout from Version Control**
Maybe you should try 
**File -> New -> Project From Version Control -> Git**
Hope this might help in your problem.

Comment: Confirmed: cloning project from Git worked, whereas downloading/extracting/importing the project Zip file did not.

Answer (score 1):

In the root directory,

Place a settings.gradle and have the following content

`include 'android'
include 'core'`

Also you may want to put a build.gradle in the root folder as well..